# Wagtail CMS render image in template without templatetags

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need render more than 100 cards with image in the template. But I noticed that each render of a photo requires a query to the database.

[image]

I upload pictures in low quality and I do not need to resize them using a template tag.

Is there a way to render an image without using template tags?

Comment: This has not (much) to do with the templatetag, you should use a `prefetch_related`.

Comment: self.pages.prefetch_related('organization__logo__renditions') don't work for me